# Why adding a column to ag-grid-react causes all cells to rerender?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an app that uses ag-grid-react 21.0.1 and when I add a column all cells rerender, which is extremely heavy and for larger grids makes the app completely unusable. Is there any way to prevent this? I pass exactly the same rowData and do not change references of other columnDefs

Answer (score 2):

You should use `columnApi.setColumnState()` to update the column visibility. Avoid `setState` (which I assume in you case) because it's unnecessary. Ag-grid will handle the rest for you. Something like this:

```
    const show = true; // or false depend on what you want
    const columnState = columnApi.getColumnState();
    const newColumnState = columnState.map((c) => {
      const nc = { ...c };
      if (c.colId === targetColId) {
        nc.hide = show;
      }
      return nc;
    });
    columnApi.setColumnState(newColumnState);
```

### Live Example

[image: Edit AgGrid Change Column Visibility]

Comment: Yeah this works but unfortunately, I don't know the names of the columns beforehand, so I can't simply hide and show them